# Getting the value of a variable from localStorage from a different javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

having a problem using localstorage in javascript. 
I have two javascript files and one multi-page html file. I'm setting the value of a variable to store in local storage in the home.js class and I then want to get the value of the same variable in my editCase.js class. Is this possible? The goal here is to use the variable several places in the html file.

home.js:

```
var _NSCaseId;
var nsId;
$("#listOfCases li").click(function(){
            nsId = $(this).attr('id');
            LocalStorage.save(_NSCaseId, nsId);
            alert(nsId);
        });
```

As you can see, the value is the id of a listview item. This works fine and the alert shows the correct value every time.

I then want to use the same variable in the editCase.js file:

```
var id = LocalStorage.get(_NSCaseId);
    alert(id);
```

But I get an error in logcat saying _NSCaseId is undefined in editCase.js

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This shouldn't be working at all. Its `localStorage` (JS is very case sensitive), and to save an item, you use `setItem`, change your syntax to:

```
//You would not define var _NSCaseId and save the var, you save a string key
localStorage.setItem('_NSCaseId', nsId); //set
```

And to get

```
localStorage.getItem('_NSCaseId');
```

See DOM Storage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

Comment: still getting undefined when I try to get it. :/

Comment: Are you on a browser that supports DOM storage?

Comment: it's a phonegap app running on android. It's using chrome

Comment: i want to use two different javascript classes. That's why I didn't post my own jsfiddle

Comment: The two different classes is irrelevant as `localStorage` will be accessible by both of them