# Setting and getting localStorage with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am trying out localStorage and attempting at getting text from a div and storing it in localStorage, however, it sets it as an [object Object] and returns [object Object]. Why is this happening?

```js
localStorage.content = $('#test').html('Test');

$('#test').html(localStorage.content);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: use JSON.stringify

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the value of a variable from localStorage from a different javascript file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861265/getting-the-value-of-a-variable-from-localstorage-from-a-different-javascript-fi)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You said you are attempting to **get the text from a div** and **store it on local storage.**

Please Note: Text and Html are different. In the question you mentioned text.  `html()` will return Html content like `<a>example</a>`. if you want to get Text content then you have to use `text()` instead of `html()` then the result will be `example` instead of `<a>example<a>`. Anyway, I am using your terminology let it be Text.

**Step 1:** get the text from div.

what you did is not get the text from div but set the text to a div.

```
$('#test').html("Test");
```

is actually setting text to div and the output will be a jQuery object. That is why it sets it as `[object Object]`.

To get the text you have to write like this
`$('#test').html();`

This will return a string not an object so the result will be `Test` in your case.

**Step 2:** set it to local storage.

Your approach is correct and you can write it as

```
localStorage.key=value
```

But the preferred approach is

`localStorage.setItem(key,value);` to set

`localStorage.getItem(key);` to get.

key and value must be strings.

so in your context code will become

```
$('#test').html("Test");
localStorage.content = $('#test').html();
$('#test').html(localStorage.content);
```

But I don't find any meaning in your code. Because you want to get the text from div and store it on local storage. And again you are reading the same from local storage and set to div.  just like `a=10; b=a; a=b;`

If you are facing any other problems please update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 43):

Use `setItem` and `getItem` if you want to write simple strings to localStorage. Also you should be using `text()` if it's the text you're after as you say, else you will get the full HTML as a string.

#### Sample using .text()

```
// get the text
var text = $('#test').text();

// set the item in localStorage
localStorage.setItem('test', text);

// alert the value to check if we got it
alert(localStorage.getItem('test'));
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/f3zLa3zc/

---

#### Storing the HTML itself

```
// get html
var html = $('#test')[0].outerHTML;

// set localstorage
localStorage.setItem('htmltest', html);

// test if it works
alert(localStorage.getItem('htmltest'));
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/psfL82q3/1/

---

### Update on user comment

A user want to update the localStorage when the div's content changes. Since it's unclear how the div contents changes (ajax, other method?) `contenteditable` and `blur()` is used to change the contents of the div and overwrite the old `localStorage` entry.

```
// get the text
var text = $('#test').text();

// set the item in localStorage
localStorage.setItem('test', text);

// bind text to 'blur' event for div
$('#test').on('blur', function() {

    // check the new text
    var newText = $(this).text();

    // overwrite the old text
    localStorage.setItem('test', newText);

    // test if it works
    alert(localStorage.getItem('test'));

});
```

If we were using ajax we would instead trigger the function it via the function responsible for updating the contents.

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/g1b8m1fc/

Comment: `.text()` and `.html()` both work identically in that with a parameter they return a jQuery object and without a parameter they return a string. There's no reason to switch using `.text()` if the OP really wants the HTML content.

Comment: Also, "If you want to store the entire HTML as a string you need to use JSON.stringify" is just wrong.

Comment: @JJJ Correct, my bad.

Comment: @JJJ OP clearly writes `attempting at getting text`. But you're correct about the object-part though. Updated answer.

Comment: @Tommie: OP also has a lack of knowledge on jQuery so terminology might not be on par and using the specified code from OP might be prudent :) In my humble opinion, the answer should contain in that case both examples, `.html()` with the additions as mentioned by @JJJ , as well as a suggested alternative of using `text()` in case that is all OP needed.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Yes, that seems to be the case. Added example of getting the HTML even though i don't really think it's what the user is after.

Comment: @werewr `when i update content of the div` how do you update the content of the div. that is not visible in the question. Please update your question with more details. then only some one can help you.

Comment: @TintuCRaju Update the content how? I added an example of overwriting the localstorage when the content is changed but it seems the question lacks information. Is the content changed via ajax or via some other method?

Comment: So downvoted by trolls for no reason i see. Answering questions on SO and being the first to actually do so seems to be pretty much useless. It's a shame.

Comment: @Tommie don't worry man. some times it happens. :-) I upvoted and appreciate your good intention.

Comment: @TintuCRaju Thanks. :)

Answer (score 7):

The [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) can only store string content and you are trying to store a jQuery object since [`html(htmlString)`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) returns a jQuery object.

You need to set the string content instead of an object. And use the [`setItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) method to add data and [`getItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) to get data.

```
window.localStorage.setItem('content', 'Test');
$('#test').html(window.localStorage.getItem('content'));
```