# To do list , I need to add the items to localstorage and get them when the page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Anyone help me to add localstorage to this Jquery code : to save the To-Do-List items to the Localstorage

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
 $("#add").on("click", function() {
 var val = $("input").val();
 if(val !== '') {
 var elem = $("<li></li>").text(val);
 $(elem).append("<button class='rem'>X</button>");
 $("#mylist").append(elem);
 $("input").val("");
 $(".rem").on("click", function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
 });
 }
 });
 });
 </script>


<h1>My To-Do List</h1>
<input type="text" placeholder="New item" />
<button id="add">Add</button>
<ol id="mylist"></ol>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting and getting localStorage with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40791207/setting-and-getting-localstorage-with-jquery)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You show your code, but as far as I can see, this code does not attempt to access localstorage.We want to encourage you to provide a [mcve] to assist us in helping you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 window.localStorage.your_data = value
```

your_data is the name you want to set and value is the value or variable you want to save.

Comment: In my example : the value is the ordered list itself ?

Comment: localStorage.list = $('#your_list'); did you try this?

Comment: Happy to help. please accept the answer if it helps

Comment: Would you please modify my code to do the function ?