# How to access variables stored in the localstorage of background page of a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm storing some data (setting the extensionId) in the background script of a chrome extension, and I need to access the stored data from the "options.html" page.I'm attempting to do so by `var id =localstorage.datafield` but it seems like there is no datafield to localstorage, however if I go to the background console of the extension, the same thing works fine.

To summarise, I want to know, how to access the localstorage variables, which are accessible in the background context, in the context of content scripts (or options page, for that matter)?

Comment: I'm assuming `localstorage` is a typo only in the question. The options page declared in manifest.json should be opened via the standard method (from the chrome://extensions page or by right-clicking the extension toolbar icon or programmatically). You can't just open it from the folder directly as it'll have a file:// URL, not chrome-extension://

Comment: you can refer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861265/getting-the-value-of-a-variable-from-localstorage-from-a-different-javascript-fi